# how much time will take to debug flutterFlow code to flutter if i use the download code option in FlutterFlow?

Tags: android, flutter, flutterflow

I have an app with about 14 screens and i need to integrate a package which will only work on android.or is there a way to add andorid only packages to flutterFlow ?

I tried adding custom functions with that package but FF was throwing abunch of errors